# Unable to get CDI working in Weblogic 12c, hibernate 5.2.4, hibernate-validator/cdi 5.3.1

Tags: cdi, weblogic12c, hibernate-5

My env: 
weblogic 12c

with jpa2.1 patch that sets: SET PRE_CLASSPATH=%MW_HOME%\oracle_common\modules\javax.persistence_2.1.jar;%MW_HOME%\wlserver\modules\com.oracle.weblogic.jpa21support_1.0.0.0_2-1.jar

my-ear/APP-INF/lib contains:

```
hibernate-release-5.2.4.Final/lib/required/*.jar 
hibernate-validator-5.3.1/dist/*.jar and hibernate-validator-5.3.1/dist/lib/required/*
```

my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
  version="2.1">
<persistence-unit name="myPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
<jta-data-source>myDataSource</jta-data-source>
```

**I am able to use persistence.xml and entityManager gets injected into my session bean without any issues.** However when I add beans.xml (to use CDI) in one of the ejb-jar/META-INF I get:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnproxyableResolutionException: WELD-001435 Normal scoped bean class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl is not proxyable because it has no no-args constructor - ValidatorBean [id=org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidatorBean_default].
```

My weblogic-application.xml contains:

```
<prefer-application-packages>       
 <package-name>antlr.*</package-name>
 <package-name>org.hibernate.*</package-name>
 <package-name>org.hibernate.validator.*</package-name>
 <package-name>org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.*</package-name>        
 <package-name>javax.validation.*</package-name>
 <package-name>javax.validation.spi.*</package-name>
<package-name>javax.validation.bootstrap.*</package-name>
```

Complete stacktrace:

```
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnproxyableResolutionException: WELD-001435 Normal scoped bean class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl is not proxyable because it has no no-args constructor - ValidatorBean [id=org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidatorBean_default].
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Proxies.getUnproxyableClassException(Proxies.java:214)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Proxies.getUnproxyableTypeException(Proxies.java:180)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Proxies.getUnproxyableTypesExceptionInt(Proxies.java:195)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Proxies.getUnproxyableTypesException(Proxies.java:169)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:151)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:388)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:371)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:379)
    at com.oracle.injection.provider.weld.WeldInjectionContainer.start(WeldInjectionContainer.java:110)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.initCdi(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:76)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.activate(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:49)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.activate(AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:587)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:398)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:371)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:379)
    at com.oracle.injection.provider.weld.WeldInjectionContainer.start(WeldInjectionContainer.java:110)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.initCdi(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:76)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.activate(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:49)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.activate(AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:587)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

What am I missing? How do I get beans.xml/CDI working in this environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed `Weblogic patches 17754607 and 23744018 (Weblogic Server 12.1.3.0.161018)`.

and removed:
`hibernate-validator-5.3.1/dist/*.jar` from `my-ear/APP-INF/lib`.

The Oracle provided validation jars worked fine - and I am now able to use CDI.